# Implicitly typed local variables must be initialized: scope definition

Tags: c#, interface

I have a code where I need to declare a "var" variable, since the type will change based on the request. This declaration has to be made inside a try block to catch any exceptions:

```
try
{
    var calc = (Type1)obj;
    var results = calc.Function();
}
catch
{
    var calc = (Type2)obj;
    var results = calc.Function();
}
finally
{
    return results;
}
```

Now the problem is, "results" will not work since the scope ends outside try catch block. There is no way I can declare var outside try, since I have to check for typecasting and change the type accordingly.

Type1, Type2 are different interfaces and obj is again "var" which can have different types.

I cannot even initiate var outside try block as null. How can I work this out?

Comment: If you initialized a `var` as `null`, what type would you expect it to be? `var` is not the same as `object` nor `dynamic`. You should really read the documentation on `var`, you are far away from understanding it.

Comment: I know, I am not looking to initialise it as null. That is not my main concern. All I am looking for is to return the "results", which can be either a dataset, or a datatable based on whether the try block executes, or catch block executes.

Comment: `var` can obfuscate your code, don't abuse it. It often makes your code much more readable and understandable if you mention the types, all the more if you use return types of methods.

Comment: Please add at least 2 examples of the different calls you might make to the method so we can determine the best path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have two point of return instead of one:

```
var results = //determine the result type here
 try
{
    var calc = (Type1)obj;
    return calc.Function();
}
catch
{
    var calc = (Type2)obj;
    return calc.Function();
}
```

**also**

you should check if obj is of type Type1 before trying the cast to avoid exceptions. 
Like this:

```
if (obj is Type1)
{
    return (obj as Type1).Function();
}
else
{
    return (obj as Type2).Function();
}
```

**Furthermore**
since you must have a return type that the two return types must conform to, you could potentially do this(but this is not recommended):

```
var result = //type of return type
    try
{
    var calc = (Type1)obj;
    result  =  calc.Function();
}
catch
{
    var calc = (Type2)obj;
    result = calc.Function();
}
finally
{
return result;
}
```

Comment: results can be a datatable, or a dataset based on the call.

Comment: either way your function return type must contain both of them (the return type must be contravariant to the two possible results)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will go ahead with your suggestions.

Comment: Why is your third approach not recommended towards the first one? I can´t see any difference here.

Comment: it is similar to the first one but recommended in respect to the second one, since in op example the exception is used to control the flow and not to handle exceptional cases

Comment: So V1 is as much not-recommended as V3.

Answer (score 0):

Best way from a clean-code-perspective is to define a common interface both `Type1` and `type2` implement:

```
interface IFoo
{
    MyType Function();
}
```

Now you don´t have to switch for the type and can easily define `result` out of your `try/catch` to let the `finally`handle it appropriately:

```
MyType result = null;
try
{
    IFoo foo = obj as IFoo;
    results = foo.Function();
}
catch
{
   ...
}
finally
{
    return results;
}
```